# Code not Working : Photo Swap using Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to get the page like.It replaces images every 10 seconds,using jquery.

### I put my code below.(Source Code: http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/post/2011/04/17/Photofy-New-Animated-Photo-Swap-Plugin-for-JQuery.aspx)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          var getData = setInterval(function()
         {
             //$('#displayData').load('anyphpfile.php?randval='+ Math.random());

          var myOptions = {
            url:'anyphpfile.php?randval='+ Math.random(),

            success: function(data) {

                $('#postDiv').html(data);
            },
            error:  function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert(XMLHttpRequest);
                  alert(textStatus);
                  alert(errorThrown); 
            }             
          }
          $("#facesPhotoWrapper").photofy(myOptions);
          }, 1000);
      });
      var imageList = [];
/*imageList = ['http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/1.jpg','http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/2.jpg',
            'http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/3.jpg','http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/4.jpg',
            'http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/5.jpg','http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/6.jpg',
            'http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/7.jpg','http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/8.jpg',
            'http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/9.jpg','http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/10.jpg'
];*/
</script>
```

```
$dbhost2 = "localhost";
$dbuser2 = "root";
$dbpassword2 = "";
$db2 = "extjs_image";
$connection2 = mysql_connect($dbhost2,$dbuser2,$dbpassword2) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db2,$connection2);  


$qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5 ";         
$result = mysql_query($qry);

$myarray=array();
$str="[";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

     $str .= "'images/".$row['image']."',";
}
$str = substr($str,0,-1);
$str .="]";
/*['images/1_01.jpg','images/1_21.jpg','images/1_11.jpg','images/1_10.jpg','images/1_25.jpg'['images/1_01.jpg','images/1_21.jpg','images/1_11.jpg','images/1_10.jpg','images/1_25.jpg']
*/
```

?>

Comment: yes,i change that to 10 Sec but first of in need to run...you can Check this reference site (badoo.com) index page

Comment: what is the problem with your code? is it not running? or are you having errors? give some details

Comment: With the static data it is working fine.But when i try to merge my PHP/Mysql Code with it.It stop working.Please guide me..I put my php code in another file "anyphpfile.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photofy isn't currently designed for real-time image updates. This is basically because you never often stay on the page for large amounts of time, so images could change on page load. However I'm interested to add this option into Photofy later down the line.

To get the effect of this, just submit a greater amount of images than what you actually want to display. In your imageList, submit 27 images for example. Now limit what is shown by setting the imagecount to 9.

You can still randomise what images are sent to Photofy on every page load. Just get your php code to return a javascript file containing the array.

```
var imageList = ['/Downloads/Faces/1.jpg','/Downloads/Faces/2.jpg','/Downloads/Faces/3.jpg']; //etc
```

So you could now do...

```
<div id="photofyWrapper"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="ImageListGenerator.php"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myOptions = {
images: imageList,
imagecount: 9
};
$("#photofyWrapper").photofy(myOptions);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have it run every second, change 1000 to 10000

UPDATE:

simply place your generated content before you set the options

```
var getData = setInterval(function()
         {
             //$('#displayData').load('anyphpfile.php?randval='+ Math.random());
          // generated content here
         var imageList = [];
         imageList = ['http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/1.jpg','http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/2.jpg',
            'http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/3.jpg','http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/4.jpg',
            'http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/5.jpg','http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/6.jpg',
            'http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/7.jpg','http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/8.jpg',
            'http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/9.jpg','http://blog.tremaynechrist.co.uk/Downloads/Faces/10.jpg'
]; 

          var myOptions = {
            url:'anyphpfile.php?randval='+ Math.random(),
            // here set the imagelist
            images: imageList,
            success: function(data) {

                $('#postDiv').html(data);
            },
            error:  function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert(XMLHttpRequest);
                  alert(textStatus);
                  alert(errorThrown); 
            }             
          }
          $("#facesPhotoWrapper").photofy(myOptions);
          }, 1000);
      });
```

Comment: if you want to use this plug in, you have to follow its guideline.
put your images in a div with id `facesPhotoWrapper`
try that and give feedback

Comment: i think you forgot to set your options `images: imageList` and you need to generate imagelist before using it